# Making a scrollbar with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I'm trying to make a scrollbar with JavaScript (jQuery) and Divs. I'm not using any plugin because I can't use it because what i'm doing it's an app for a TV.

I've also read some code from a few plugins but with no luck...

This is what i got http://jsfiddle.net/joseadrian/HEp7U/2/
But what i'm trying to do is a copy of the real scrollbar on his left. And I need those buttons 'Subir'(Up) and 'Bajar'(Down) because you can't use a mouse, only the TV Control.

What am I doing wrong?

I hope you can understand me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like its working. what is the issue?

Comment: Here is a fiddle with correct overflow: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/HEp7U/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/HEp7U/7/

Here is a version based off yours where you can see the start and the end: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/CsJ79/

Comment: I think I'm stupid... I didn't notice the height of the red div container :(. Thanks for changing the background. Haha.

Comment: @Jose no prob jose -- that's why indenting helps ^_^